# How to get selected UITableViewCell's origin in the TableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, frame

As the tableView is scrolling it is difficult to know its current position on the screen by 
multiplication heightForRowAtIndex for all rows before selected.

Is there other way to get **Y coordinate** of **selected tableViewCell** in the **tableView** or in the **screen**?
I try to get cell frame or bounds , but get (0,0,0,0) rectangle in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the scrollView is scrolling, position of what on it is not changed,
In fact is the content view moved.

Tableview is a kind of scrollview. You can get a property "contentOffset", that may help you.